# How to get a json value from json file using ansible jinja

Tags: json, ansible

I have my json file in files foder of playbook,I need to get a specific value of "ending" value from my json file ,how can i do it.

Here is my try:

```
 - set_fact:
      usr: "{{ (lookup('file','{{ role_path }}/files/inputfile.json')) |      from_json }}"

- set_fact:
     user: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
      "{{ usr['meta'] | map(attribute='ending') | list }}"

My Inputjsonfile:


  {
    "mydata": {
         "pair": [
            "key": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAgOh +            Afb0oQEnvHifHuzBwl + Tiu8LXoJXb / ii / ehfNpJZLi1Ns8Wns4n5y8U6K0qE8E1bs / kedSUM30euKUu4YYnT5pDJT + kroo2fpsxM0nhrCRjUxCzClRSo41V / Q2a3QOSLPRXf
                  GL / Sf9kJVSRc6YmKDcnNkylqYWk4Ts0AP4fFTgZxbZQ6T6KQxEKeiKO + CQyvQi8ZL75UmmhbtM5R
                  qDTriXmPR3v4OHVTFx7zJzT2uZYxL4nNcsFi0mJLP + AvSkucIThOQcS64KVFLmxvJghSVyB + ZUfx
                  wrUhAORF / Q3zuIj +                    a9BDLTg3jMYkBC7NdAeYxAuHisJJMgEmmTU5qgPrkSabCPKJhCP3
                    -- -- - END RSA PRIVATE KEY-- -- - "
                     }
                   ],
                "name": "Jonhm",
                "centre": "saquel"
                    }

                          }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the error message? I see that your JSON file is not valid – I guess `shops` supposed to be a list of strings, but now it is a list with single malformed dict.

Comment: Error message like this:  FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\n and [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Skipping task due to undefined Error, in the future this will be a fatal error.: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'metadata'.
This feature will
be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your JSON file is malformed.
Make `shops` this:

```
    "shops": [
          "mart",
          "flip",
          "amazon"
    ]
```

Or this:

```
   "shops": [
        {
          "mart": 0,
          "flip": 0,
          "amazon": 0
        }
   ]
```

And error will go away.

Comment: thanks,but i have changed like this..Now showing another error like this: {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable em' is undefined\n\n  .Also whats the difference between from_json and to_json.It didnot take from_json so I gave to_json ,it gives output with \\n \\\"values"

Comment: `from_json` makes object from JSON string – this is what you need. `to_json` – reverse process. Run you playbook with `-vv` switch and make sure that `usr` is what you want. If it is not, check your JSON syntax with validator (e.g. http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Suvorov i have edited my query,in that i changed my json,when iam doing in jsonlint it shows invalidate ,in that case while doing debug module i get a correct json format ,but when i using set_fact with from_json it didnot get validate,Why it so get differs like that?

Comment: @Doefi why have you changed the question's data entirely? Anyway – your JSON data is invalid!